# How to know if the user has entered data in QTableView

Tags: qt, model, qtableview

I currently have a Qtablview attached to a model. The user can enter data in specific cells of a table. Is there any signal of QtableView that I can connect to and find out what the user entered and in which cell was the data entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know whether or not data changed you should be looking at the model, not the view. That's what the model is for. There are a variety of ways to get the information you want depending on what kind of model you're using. For example, the [QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal.